# Calling right overload of the java method from jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I am using java library, that has overloaded methods in the class that I use.

```
JAVA:
void f(float[]);
void f(Object[]);
```

Now I call this class from jython, and I want to call the Object[] overload. The problem is that python sees my array as array of floats, and therefore calls the wrong overload methods.

```
JYTHON:
f([[1, 1.0])
```

How to force the Object[] method to be executed?

Answer (score 2):

It took me considerable amount of time to find out, so I decided to post a question together with the answer.

### Forcing the right overload

Jython documentation tells that in order to to force a call of right overload you should cast arguments to java objects manually before the call:

```
from java.lang import Byte
foo(Byte(10))
```

However that doesn't work with java arrays.

### Forcing the right overload for array

http://www.jython.org/archive/22/userguide.html#java-arrays

It's possible to create java arrays in jython. For example the following code will create in jython java array of type int[]

```
from jarray import array
array(python_array, 'i')
```

You can create Object[] like this, and force java to call the right overload.

```
from jarray import array
from java.lang import Object
oa = array(python_array, Object)
f(oa)
```